# Roots of Equations in the unit Circle and Quadrants

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been stuck on this problem for a long time :

Prove that $8z^4-6z+5=0$ has one root in each quadrant.

I have not obtained the required results........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a. :

It is easy to prove that the equation has no real roots, and that the equation has no purely imaginary roots.

Now let $\alpha,\overline\alpha,\beta,\overline\beta$ be the roots of the equation.

Then, by Vieta's formulas, we have
$$\alpha+\overline\alpha+\beta+\overline\beta=0\quad\Rightarrow \quad\Re(\alpha)=-\Re(\beta).$$

Comment: And what about b ?? (is there anyway to use Rouche??)

Comment: @herashefat: Asking more than one question per post is discouraged. That's why I answered only the first one.

Comment: How can I solve the second one?? Hints would be nice.....

Comment: @herashefat: As I said, please ask it as a new question because asking more than one question per post is discourged here. Also, please finish the question a. Does my answer help?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ....I am now reviewing Vieta's formulas ....Should i post another question now(about part b??)

Comment: @herashefat: And yes, you can post another question for b.

Comment: Hi could you please explain your last deduction a bit more??

Comment: @herashefat: We have $\alpha+\overline\alpha+\beta+\overline\beta=0$ by Vieta's formulas. Then, if we write $\alpha=a+bi,\beta=c+di$ where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R$, then we have $a+bi+a-bi+c+di+c-di=0$, i.e. $2a+2c=0$, i.e. $a=-c$. This is equivalent to $\Re(\alpha)=-\Re(\beta)$. I hope this helps.